# Calculating time between two overrided methods

Tags: python

I'm working on a python program and I want to calculate the time between TWO overrided methods. This is my code:

```
from time import time

........
# Code
........

class management:
start_time = time()
    def method1(effect):
        time1 = time() - start_time
        print(f'{effect.src_file} from the method2 started successfully')
        return time1
    
    def method2(effect):
        time2 = time() - start_time()
        print(f'{effect.src_file} from the method2 started successfully')
        return time2

effect_one = management.method1
effect_two = management.method2

.......
# Code
.......
```

Now the problem is I don't know when the method1 or method2 is going to execute. It could be anytime between the program runtime.

***So How do I get the time interval between two methods.***

**Note: When a method gets executed, other method gets executed right after it (unknown time for me!)**

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of the object, so you have a place to store the numbers.  After method2 runs, you can print out the delta at any time.

```
from time import time

class Management:
    start = 0
    delta = 0
    def method1(self, effect):
        self.start  = time() 
        print(f'{effect.src_file} from the method1 started successfully')
        return time1

    def method2(self,effect):
        self.delta = time() - self.start
        print(f'{effect.src_file} from the method2 started successfully')
        return time2

management = Management()
effect_one = management.method1
effect_two = management.method2

# Code

print( "Elapsed was", management.delta, "seconds" )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pollute your `management` class with time-related attributes, you can delegate it to another class, let's call it `Timer`:

```
import time
import functools

class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = None
        self.end_time = None
        
    def start(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def _(*args, **kwargs):
            self.start_time = time.time()
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return _
        
    def stop(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def _(*args, **kwargs):
            self.end_time = time.time()
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return _
        
    @property
    def diff_time(self):
        return self.end_time - self.start_time
```

This class contains two decorator methods: `start`, which will set the `start_time` attribute whenever its decorated function starts; and `end`, which will set the `end_time` attribute whenever its decorated function starts. It also contains a `diff_time` property, which will store the time difference between end and start times.

Now, let's suppose your class looks like this:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print("bar called")
    
    def baz(self):
        print("baz called")
```

You can create a `Timer` instance and wrap the wanted methods: in this case, we'll calculate the difference calling time between `bar` and `baz`:

```
timer = Timer()
Foo.bar = timer.start(Foo.bar)
Foo.baz = timer.stop(Foo.baz)
```

Then, just run your code as normal:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.bar()
time.sleep(2)
foo.baz()
```

When you've finished the measurement, you can check how many seconds it passed:

```
print(timer.diff_time)
# Outputs 2.002431869506836
```

Comment: You solution is good but there is one particular problem. Problem is : I don't know when my functions are going to be called. Because that depends on the OS. That's why it won't work. In your code I can call the function anytime but in my code I can't. When I use your function, it says 'NONETYPE'. I hope you understand!